# Populating selectItems of the combobox (label, value) using a managed bean

Tags: xpages

I have a combo in my page which I want to have populated with some keywords from configuration. I want to use a managed bean to accomplish it.

Let's say that I have a bean called Config, where there is a List categories field. ..

```
public class Configuration implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<String> categories;

    public List<String> getCategories() {
        if (categories == null)
            categories = getCats();

        return categories;
    }

    //... etc.
}
```

When I use this field for my combo, it works well...

```
<xp:comboBox>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{config.categories}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

But, it's only a list of labels. I need values, too. How do I populate selectItems of my combo with TWO strings - a label and a value?

EDIT:

I tried to create an object Combo with label and value fields and use a repeat inside my comboBox.

```
<xp:comboBox>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{config.combo}" var="c" rows="30">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="#{c.label}" itemValue="#{c.value}" />
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Still not working... :-(

Comment: Use a pipe (`|`) delimiter... e.g. `someList.add("I'm a label|I'm a value");`

Comment: Ok, a pipe works, but it's a silly solution. What if that keyword string contains a pipe char? Isn't there another solution with using simple object and some sort of converter?

Comment: I wouldn't call it silly. It's more tradition as separating label and value by pipe is common in Notes for decades already, e.g. for Dialog list choices . You still have the possibility to replace a pipe in your data with another char. But honestly, which data contains a pipe by nature?

Comment: I know it's a tradition in Notes development and honestly I hoped that nonconceptual stuff like this will disapear in JSF development.

Comment: Now I see, Mark's code is of course much better than using pipe, especially SelectItemGroup is a nice add on :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of returning a `List<String>` your function should return a `List<javax.faces.model.SelectItem>`. Here's a sample:

```
public static List<SelectItem> getComboboxOptions() {

    List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    SelectItem option = new SelectItem();
    option.setLabel("Here's a label");
    option.setValue("Here's a value");

    options.add(option);

    return options;
}
```

Advantage of using this method (besides not having to use that nonconceptual stuff :-) is that you can also the `SelectItemGroup` class to group the options:

```
public static List<SelectItem> getGroupedComboboxOptions() {

    List<SelectItem> groupedOptions = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    SelectItemGroup group = new SelectItemGroup("A group of options");

    SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[2];

    options[0] = new SelectItem("here's a value", "here's a label");
    options[1] = new SelectItem("here's a value", "here's a label");

    group.setSelectItems(options);

    groupedOptions.add(group);

    return groupedOptions;
}
```

Comment: Mark, Can you give a quick example of how to use this?  Maybe because it is Friday afternoon and I leave in an hour, but I am having trouble figuring out the proper way to invoke it.  Thank you.

Comment: Put the code above in a Java class in your database. In my examples the classes are static, so you don't need to create a Java bean first. You can use it in a `xp:comboBox` using the syntax in the question: `<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1"><xp:selectItems><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:eu.linqed.YourClass.getComboboxOptions()}]]></xp:this.value></xp:selectItems></xp:comboBox>`

Comment: Mark, Thanks!!  I had it in 'data', not 'values'. I knew is was something dumb. Congrats on your national team in the world cup.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SelectItems`. (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html)

You can specify both value and label, or value only.

```
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

public List<SelectItem> getCategories() {
    try {
        ArrayList<SelectItem> ret = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        ret.add(new SelectItem("my value", "my label"));
        return ret;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```