# Getting array values from a Bean to an xpage through ssjs

Tags: javascript, javabeans, xpages-ssjs

By using vector got a String array from POJO.

The code is,

```
    var v = new com.vijay.Test1();
var vec:java.util.Vector=new java.util.Vector();
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
vec.addElement(v.name[i]);
return vec;
```

Where **'name'** is a String array object in the POJO.

How to do the same with a Bean class if i have getters and setters for a String array?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21547651/785061

Comment: I tried it and failed. I'm now just trying to get the values from a db and then use it somewhere. That was specifically for a combobox it seems. But didn't work for a combobox too for me. Any other alternative?