# Use SSJS only to populate Dojo Combo box and include separate itemLabel and itemValue

Tags: xpages

I am supporting my companies oldest and first XPages application.  The app does not use java for anything and uses SSJS for everything. I do not wish to start using java beans for just this one task.

This question deals with the java way to do the same thing I need: [Populating selectItems of the combobox (label, value) using a managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532641/populating-selectitems-of-the-combobox-label-value-using-a-managed-bean)  (although this I know this is the better way, I am trying to stick to the pattern established already)

The app loads all keywords into applicationScope and then uses them when needed.  I am trying to load display values and return the associated value when stored. This is similar to how traditional Notes behaved for years.

I changed the applicationScope values to store the values after a pipe (|) but I haven't figured out how to use the value using SSJS.  I am starting to doubt that it is even possible.

I tried using the core combobox control instead of the Dojo combo box to generate the code I would need.  It appears like you cannot use separate "formula items" for label and value.  Has anyone out there come up with a solution for this one, short of using a java collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Java solution in SSJS. You just need `var` instead of the initial class name and the full class names in the `new` references, so java.util.ArrayList instead of ArrayList and javax.faces.model.SelectItem instead of SelectItem. See here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/xpages-best-practice-computed-selection-lists?opendocument&comments.

So the code in the StackOverflow question you linked to converted to SSJS should be:

```
var options = new java.util.ArrayList();

var option = new javax.faces.model.SelectItem();
option.setLabel("Here's a label");
option.setValue("Here's a value");

options.add(option);

return options;
```

Comment: Going with this answer because: building the collection, adding to it, and then passing the whole collection suits how I am reading from application scope. Thanks Paul

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java class `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` in SSJS to populate the selectItems:

```
    <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                var item1 = new javax.faces.model.SelectItem("Value1", "Label1");
                var item2 = new javax.faces.model.SelectItem("Value2", "Label2");
                [item1, item2]
            }]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
        ...
    </xp:comboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing your question, since my response is fairly simple, but to compute the labels and values using JavaScript, create a JavaScript array of strings where each string has the format of "Label|Value" (the vertical bar is the separator as in a Domino field).

Howard