# XPages checkbox group - binding to a hashmap

Tags: checkbox, hashmap, xpages

I have a Hashmap (sessionScope) containing the names of guests and their UNIDs.

For example, in the hashmap below, Carmen Adamson is the key. The values of guests in her cabin are: Carmen Adamson and Stephen Adamson. The alias for each checkbox field is the Guest UNID and the values are separated by a "~".

CARMEN ADAMSON  STEPHEN ADAMSON | 1C145A291A5DFEC188257E200071402E~CARMEN ADAMSON | 813B80C332EC192188257E2000714030

Can someone help me with some example code on how I can bind a checkbox group field directly to a hashmap?

Thanks so much,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out:

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1">
<xp:selectItems>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var iterator:java.util.Iterator =     sessionScope.guestlistArray.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
var entry = iterator.next();
var guestlist = entry.getValue();
}
@Explode(guestlist,"~");}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dan, you can certainly do this, but will have to use java to accomplish it. You can write a method to pass the hashmap and return the SelectItem objects with the data and labels. I could be wrong, but I don't think it can be done through SSJS.

See this related question that has an excellent answer from Mark Leusink and includes a code example.

[Populating selectItems of the combobox (label, value) using a managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532641/populating-selectitems-of-the-combobox-label-value-using-a-managed-bean)

This example is from my blog that gives more detail in creating SelectItems using java. My example was for a ComboBox, but the checkbox also uses the SelectItem. The question above was the basis for what I wrote.

http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2015/05/using-db2-in-xpages-part-6-populating.html

Comment: Thanks,Steve! I was hoping not to have to go down the Java route. But I will if that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Steve, now that I have it working in SSJS, I'll try and find some time to investigate the Java option too.