# How to apply a style to an hiearchial comboBox in XPages

Tags: combobox, xpages, ssjs

I have a comboBox in XPages which is showing an hierarcal list of categories and values populates as a vector in SSJS.

I now want to apply a styleheet (bold) to the categories (i.e on only the categories of the generated option tags)

[image]

please note that I do not need a lesson in how stylesheets work. I need to know how to add a class or style to the categories in the outputted options tags

how can I do that?

thanks

Thomas

```
 UPDATED MY QUESTION WITH A WORKING CLASS
```

Mimics a categorized view with 3 columns in a comboBox,  category, label and value

```
public class Utils {

    public static List<SelectItem> getGroupedComboboxOptions() {

        try {

            Database db = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
            View vv = db.getView("ProdukterByCat");

            Vector v = vv.getColumnValues(0);
            List<SelectItem> groupedOptions = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            SelectItemGroup group;

            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {

                List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
                group = new SelectItemGroup(v.get(i).toString());
                ViewEntryCollection nvec = vv.getAllEntriesByKey(v.get(i), true);
                ViewEntry entry = nvec.getFirstEntry();

                while (entry != null) {

                    SelectItem option = new SelectItem(entry.getColumnValues().get(2).toString(),entry.getColumnValues().get(1).toString());
                    options.add(option);
                    entry = nvec.getNextEntry(entry);
                }
                group.setSelectItems(options.toArray(new SelectItem[options.size()]));
                groupedOptions.add(group);
            }
            return groupedOptions;

        } catch (NotesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combobox in XPages is rendered using a HTML `select` tag. If you organise the options in `optgroup`'s (see also [Populating selectItems of the combobox (label, value) using a managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532641/populating-selectitems-of-the-combobox-label-value-using-a-managed-bean/21547651#21547651)) you get some default styling out of the box. Example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup).

You can even apply additional styling on them with standard CSS by targeting the `optgroup`. But support for that is limited: it doesn't work on an iPad for example.

If you want more control on how your dropdowns look, I'd suggest to use a plugin like [Select2](https://select2.org/).

Comment: Mark is spot on, I have used the Select2 before and also the optgroups and they will do exactly what you want...

Comment: thanks , works great. I have updated my question with the solution